# Merging two dataframes in R with different variables

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with 2 column lists (2 variabels):

```
column 1 column 2
1        324
2        NA
3        NA
4        1
45       NA
325      1
4556     NA
```

which i like to merge with another dataframe that i have that has 8 variables:

```
 column 1 column 2 column 3 column 4  column 5 column 6  column 7 column8
    1        324     1        324        etc.                 etc.
    2        NA      1        324
    2        NA      1        324
    2        NA      1        324
    2        NA      1        324
```

How can i do so?

Comment: `merge()` might help. And you might want to read related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right?rq=1).

Comment: You would need to show the second data.frame (filling in the "etc" part) as well as expected output. But you might find an answer in the link @symbolrush posted.